# Is a set defined by a continuous map necessarily closed?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, hilbert-spaces

One of the proofs given in my course on metric spaces is the following:

---

**Claim**

Consider the Hilbert space $ℓ^2$ of square-summable real sequences with inner product

$$\langle x,y\rangle = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} x_n y_n $$
For $x = (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ and $y = (y_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$.

Then the set $B = \{x \in ℓ^2 : \|x\|=1\}$ is closed.

**Proof**

The function $\| \bullet \|$ is continuous, therefore the set $B$ is closed.

---

My question is, why does the continuity of the norm directly imply that $B$ is closed, and does this hold in general, for all continuous functions and metric spaces?

Comment: This set is the pre-image of the closed set \{ 1 \} via the norm function.

Comment: There is an important theorem for metric spaces $X$: closed sets are characterized as $\{ x: f(x) \in C \}$, where $f: X \to \Bbb{R}$ is a continuous map, and $C \subseteq \Bbb{R}$ is closed in $\Bbb{R}$. In particular, if you take $f=|| \cdot ||$, and $C= \{ 1 \}$, you get what you have.

Comment: Thanks guys! I had been trying to view the set $B$ as the image of some map, not as the (now pretty natural seeming) preimage that it clearly is. Long day.

Comment: @Crostul How can you take $f$ to be norm if we don't know that $X$ is a normed space or an inner product space?